# From the representation free form of the scattering amplitude to the position representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, notation

The scattering amplitude is given in an representation free manner by

$f(\vec{k},\vec{k}^{\prime})=-\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} ⟨\vec{k}|V|ψ⟩$

How can I deduce the explicit form in the space represantation. I figured that:
 $f(\vec{k},\vec{k}^{\prime})=-\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} ⟨\vec{k}|V|ψ⟩ = -\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} \int_{\Re^3}⟨\vec{k}|ψ⟩⟨\psi|V|ψ⟩ \text{d}^3\vec{r}$,
but I am not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you insert those $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ along with the integration over $d^3\vec{r}$? I think what you wanted to do is use the completeness of the position eigenvectors,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\vec{r} \; |\vec{r}\rangle\langle\vec{r}| = \mathbb{1}
\end{equation}
and write,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(\vec{k},\vec{k}^{\prime})&=−\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} \langle\vec{k}|\mathbb{1}V|\psi\rangle \\
&= −\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\vec{r} \; \langle\vec{k}|\vec{r}\rangle\langle\vec{r}|V|\psi\rangle \\
&= −\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\vec{r} \; \underbrace{\langle\vec{k}|\vec{r}\rangle}_{\psi^{*}_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})} V(\vec{r})\underbrace{\langle\vec{r}|\psi\rangle}_{\psi(\vec{r})} \\
&= −\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\vec{r} \; \frac{e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} V(\vec{r}) \psi(\vec{r})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In the second line, the unity was decomposed in terms of the position eigenstates, while in the third line, the fact that the potential $V(\hat{\vec{r}})$ is an eigenvalue of the position eigenstates was used,
\begin{equation}
\hat{V}|\vec{r}\rangle = V(\hat{\vec{r}})|\vec{r}\rangle = V(\vec{r}) |\vec{r}\rangle
\end{equation}

Also, be kind enough to explain what your notation means. Obviously $|\vec{k}\rangle$ is a momentum-$\vec{k}$ eigenstate, but where does $\vec{k}^{\prime}$ come from?

Edit:

$\psi_{\vec{k}}$ is the eigenstate of the momentum operator, \begin{equation}\hat{\vec{p}} = -i\hbar \vec{\nabla}\end{equation} in the position space with eigenvalue $\hbar\vec{k}$. If you solve the equation, \begin{equation}\hat{\vec{p}}\psi_{\vec{k}} = \hbar \vec{k}\psi_{\vec{k}}\end{equation} then you will find these exponential solutions. The factor $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}$ comes from the ``normalization'' condition,
\begin{equation}
\int d^3\vec{r}\; \psi^{*}_{\vec{k}}\psi_{\vec{k^{\prime}}} = \delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k^{\prime}})
\end{equation}

The potential $V$ is assumed to be a function of only the position $\vec{r}$ which is almost always the case, so $\hat{V} = V(\hat{\vec{r}})$. In general if a state $|n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of an operator $\hat{A}$ , then it is obviously an eigenstate of any function of that operator $f(\hat{A})$,
\begin{equation}
if \;\; \hat{A}|n\rangle=a_{n}|n\rangle \;\;\;\;then\;\;\;\; f(\hat{A})|n\rangle = f(a_{n})|n\rangle
\end{equation}
which you can easily prove by Taylor expanding the function, hence $\hat{V}|\vec{r}\rangle = V(\hat{\vec{r}})|\vec{r}\rangle = V(\vec{r}) |\vec{r}\rangle$

Comment: Why is $\psi_k=\frac{\exp(-i\vec{k}\vec{r})}{(2\pi^{3/3})}$ and why is the potential (a function) be an eigenvalue of the position eigenstates?

Comment: @Mark `\psi_{\vec{k}}=\frac{exp(-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})}{(2\pi)^{3/2}`

Comment: I have edited the answer to include your last questions. Sorry, I don't know how to write math in comments...